# Regular swap contract [SOLIDITY]

Tags: solidity, swap

I am trying to create solidity contract to swap Goreli ETH to Link, but any transaction i try to make it fails, can any one spot an issue with it ?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

// Import Uniswap V2 router and factory contracts
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";

// Import the ERC20 token contract
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract UniswapTrade {
    // Declare the Uniswap V2 router and factory contracts
    IUniswapV2Router02 public router;
    IUniswapV2Factory public factory;
    
    // Constructor function to set the router address and factory address
    constructor(address routerAddress, address factoryAddress) {
        router = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress);
        factory = IUniswapV2Factory(factoryAddress);
    }
    
    // Function to swap one token for another
    function swapTokensForTokens(
        address tokenIn,
        address tokenOut,
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external {
        // Get the path for the swap (tokenIn -> tokenOut)
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tokenIn;
        path[1] = tokenOut;
        
        // Transfer the input tokens to the contract
        IERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
        
        // Approve the router to spend the input tokens on behalf of the contract
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(address(router), amountIn);
        
        // Swap tokens on Uniswap V2
        router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amountIn,
            amountOutMin,
            path,
            to,
            deadline
        );
    }
}
```

These are the factory and router address i am using for constructer :

Factory : 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f
Router : 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D

These are the input for transaction that i am testing :

tokenIn : 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6
tokenOut : 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
amountIn : 1000000000000000
amountOutMin : 19000000000000000000
to : myWallet
deadline : blocktime

Thank you in advance!

Deploying works, transaction doesn't work ( fails with no errors )

Comment: Did you approve tokens to be `transferFrom` the `msg.sender` before calling your function `swapTokensForTokens`. Otherwise, `IERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);` will fail. Consider removing this line and making `swapTokensForTokens` payable as well as using `msg.value`.